# Create list of values from kwargs keys

Tags: python, list, keyword-argument

How can I get a list of values from kwargs (see example below), I am able to get keys but not the values

Kwargs:

> {'description_9': u'  HVAC Ductwork Upgrade ', 'state_9': u'NSW',
>   'hours_6': u'2', 'hours_5': u'1', 'hours_4': u'1', 'hours_3': u'1',
>   'hours_2': u'8', 'hours_1': u'5', 'state_1': u'NSW', 'state_3':
>   u'NSW', 'state_2': u'NSW', 'state_5': u'NSW', 'state_4': u'NSW',
>   'state_7': u'NSW', 'state_6': u'NSW', 'nbn_2': u' No ', 'nbn_3': u'
>   Yes ', 'nbn_1': u' No ', 'nbn_6': u' Yes ', 'nbn_7': u' Yes ',
>   'nbn_4': u' No ', 'nbn_5': u' Yes ', 'nbn_8': u' Yes ', 'nbn_9': u'
>   Yes ', 'site_8': u'Dee Why ', 'site_9': u'Sefton ', 'hours_9': u'4',
>   'site_2': u'Paddington ', 'site_3': u'Lidcombe ', 'site_1':
>   u'Paddington ', 'site_6': u'St Marys ', 'site_7': u'Various ',
>   'site_4': u'Parramatta ', 'site_5': u'Kingsgrove ', 'spwo_8': u'
>   SP30073989-2 ', 'spwo_9': u' SP30074031-1 ', 'spwo_4': u' SP30071948-1
>   ', 'spwo_5': u' SP30073129-1 ', 'spwo_6': u' SP30073989-1 ', 'spwo_7':
>   u' SP30073989-3 ', 'spwo_1': u' SP30063647-1 ', 'spwo_2': u'
>   SP30066349-1 ', 'spwo_3': u' SP30071798-1 ', 'hours_8': u'2',
>   'hours_7': u'3',  'description_2': u'  Lvl 5 CHW PCU Upgrade ',
>   'description_3': u'  Ductwork Upgrade ', 'description_1': u'  Chilled
>   Water Riser Upgrade ', 'description_6': u'  HVAC Dropper Upgrade ',
>   'description_7' : u'  HVAC Dropper Upgrade ', 'project_manager':
>   u'Ossama Rihani', 'state_8': u'NSW', 'description_8': u'  HVAC Dropper
>   Upgrade ', 'description_5': u'  HVAC and SGP Upgrade ',
>   'description_4': u'  Main Distribution Board LCR Automatic Transfer
>   Switches Design & Construction P2 '}

Code to extract keys with a filter:

```
state_keys = [key for key in kwargs if key.startswith("state_")]
```

Code i am trying to get the key values - not complete:

```
state_values = [value for key, value in kwargs if key.startswith("state_")]
```

Comment: `state_values = [value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key.startswith("state_")]` ...

Comment: I do not agree it is a duplicate

Comment: state_values = [kwargs[key] for key in kwargs if key.startswith("state_")]

Comment: @zwer you have answered the question, please put this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a simple reference to [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) should be counted a full fledged answer but since you insist:

```
state_values = [value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key.startswith("state_")]
```

The issue was due to `kwargs` being a `dict`, and if you want to do a parameter expansion into `key` and `value`, you have to use `kwargs.items()`. This will return a list of key-value tuples which can then be readily expanded into, well, `key` and `value`.

Beware that in Python 2.x [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) creates a whole list of key-value tuples instead of just giving you an iterator. To avoid needless resource usage, use [`dict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Kwargs is a dict, so just use `items()`  in order to iterate over it.

`state_values = [value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key.startswith("state_")]`